# Callback respond while in Thread needed

Tags: java, android, multithreading

*Current State:*
I'm using `Android SDK Version 26`.
I've got `Thread`, within the `Thread` is a `while` Loop, which increase an `Integer`. After increasing an `Integer`, the `Thread` sleeps for `X millis`. `Class A initialized Class B` and `Class B` starts the `Thread` after been `initialized`. `Class B` don't know that `Class A` exist.

*My Problem:*
I want to respond the current `Integer` value to another `Class`, every time the `while` Loop iterates.

*What I tried so far:*
I've used a `Callable<Integer>`, but it respond **after** the Thread finished. (Tested with `Log` and `System.out.println`).

*`Class B` Code:*

```
public void doSomethingBig(Integer comparedVal){  
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Integer val = new Integer(0);
            while(val < comparedVal){
                val += 1;
                // Insert Solution here
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

*`Class A` Code:*

```
public void init(){  
     B b = new B();
     b.doSomethingBig(new Integer(20));
     // Foreach Tick is made in `Thread` from `Class B`, get the `val` and do something with it. 
}
```

I need to get the `val` value, for another `Class`, which hasn't any `reference` to the `Class`, which initialized `Class B`.
Any Advice would be helpful and Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really don't get it. `Class A` need the values which are within the `Thread` of another `Class`. After `X` Seconds the `Thread` will be Closed. Before it get closed (cause it finished), I need every "Progress" to make further Operations in the `Class A`.

Comment: What can I do, to catch the `val` and respond it to `Class A`, without having `Class B` to `initialize Class A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the progress represented by an integer, you can use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Inncrements the progress counter like this:

```
AtomicInteger val = new AtomicInteger();
int newVal = val.incrementAndGet();
```

And, get this value from another thread like this:

```
int progress = val.get();
```